# Are there any R packages that handle Bluetooth connections?

Tags: r

In a nutshell, I wrote a Shiny app for collecting data in the field. Part of this collection process includes scanning specimens with a Biomark HPR Lite (https://www.biomark.com/Documents%20and%20Settings/67/Site%20Documents/PDFs/HPRLiteUserManualRev12018-02-15EN.pdf) RFID reader capable of Bluetooth transmission. It would be fantastic if RFID data could populate a specific field within my Shiny application.

I'm sure this is possible one way or another, but my Bluetooth knowledge is scant and preliminary searches have not yielded any results. Any ideas from the R community?

Thanks,
`Brian`

Comment: `s/with an RFID reader/with _this_ RFID reader: $RFID_READER_INFO/`. Decent, modern USB RFID readers generally have a USB HID mode. Translated: a decent, modern, good, non-crappy RFID reader should let you have a user put focus on an input text field, scan the RFID tag and then have it automagically converted to keyboard events that will fill in that field. But, we don't know what you have. Also: this is very likely going to get closed given that it fits squarely in an off-topic category.

Comment: If you are unfortunate enough to have an inelegant reader you may be able to write a web usb driver for the device (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176940/1457051)

Comment: Thanks for answering @hrbrmstr. I've searched and replaced as you've asked. Reader is new, but not necessarily elegant and non-crappy. I should have time to fiddle with this soon; wish me luck!